# D3.JS: Variável com getElementById com valor default

Tags: javascript, variáveis, d3.js, default

Estou a criar uma visualização em D3.js, na qual estou a fazer o import da data através de uma string dinâmica que requer uma variável, que dei o nome de honeystring.

**Variável**

```
var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear");
```

**Import**

```
d3.json( `data/HoneyProduction-${honeyyear}.json`, function( honey_data ){...
```

Tendo em conta que o elemento do Id `vardatayear` não existe antes da visualização existir, como garanto que a variável tem um valor, como 2013, caso o elemento não exista ou seja nulo?

Isto é, o que deva fazer para fazer assignment de um valor à variàvel, por default?

Comment: Você quer que sua var `honeyyear` venha com valor 2013 caso o elemento não exista ou seja `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

`var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear") || 2013;`

caso `document.getElementById("vardatayear")` seja nullo ou nao exista a var `honeyyear` vem com valor de 2013.

Ou com um `if` você consegue tambem:

```
var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear")

if(!honeyyear){
    honeyyear  = 2013
}
```

Comment: tente usar `var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear").value`